# Parse network response bytes without converting to String

Tags: json, moshi

For security reasons, I do not want to use the `fromJson(string: String)` to parse `JSON`.
This method accepts a `string` as parameter which means the entire network response is in memory as a `String`. Since strings are immutable in Java, it is advised to not use them to handle sensitive information.

My question is,
Can `Moshi` parse the network response `bytes` to any model class without requiring conversion to `String` ?
Can the methods `fromJson(source: BufferedSource)` or `fromJson(reader: JsonReader)` be used for this purpose ?

Comment: Yes, use those methods to read the bytes off the wire. You can read Okio's API to learn more; Okio makes handling bytes easy.

Comment: And these methods will not convert the response to string internally ? correct ?

Comment: no. they will not buffer the source into memory at all. you can stream right from the source.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EricCochran.. Much Appreciated :)